# Tag synonym request: [iphone-simulator] and [ipad-simulator] -> [ios-simulator]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

There are two tags [iphone-simulator](/questions/tagged/iphone-simulator) and [ipad-simulator](/questions/tagged/ipad-simulator) which means [ios-simulator](/questions/tagged/ios-simulator) on StackOverflow. I suggest to make both a synonym for [ios-simulator](/questions/tagged/ios-simulator).

Comment: I retagged a few questions that I'd answered under the [iphone-simulator] tag so that I'd have enough votes in the tag, and I went ahead and added the synonyms.  Unfortunately, only one other person has enough votes in the tag to vote for these right now.  Some retagging might solve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the premise, and would have used [ios-simulator](/questions/tagged/ios-simulator) if I'd been the first to create the tags, but don't ignore the fact that [iphone-simulator](/questions/tagged/iphone-simulator) has **1,012 questions**, [ipad-simulator](/questions/tagged/ipad-simulator) has **95 questions**, and [ios-simulator](/questions/tagged/ios-simulator) has **29 questions**.

Is there any harm in making a distinction between the simulator as used for the iPhone and iPad?  This merge would loose the information contained in the previous 1100 applications of that distinction.  Sure, they're the same app, and sure, you need to also search for [iphone-simulator] when researching a problem you encounter while using the iOS simulator for the iPad, but it seems a little extreme to merge 1100 questions into a tag with 29 questions.

I'm not opposed to the merge or synonym, but these numbers should be considered.

Comment: What information would be lost, the questions would then all have the `ios-simulator` tag (assuming they did the batch retag also)?

Comment: @LanceRoberts - The `iphone-simulator` questions are about the simulator being used with iPhone software, and the `ipad-simulator` questions are about the simulator being used with iPad software.  If the simulator does what you need it to for the iPhone, but something's not right with the iPad version, right now you can find 95 questions specific to the use of the simulator with the iPad.  After the proposed merge, you wouldn't be able to.

Comment: Yeh, I imagine that for problems specific to either you'd also want an [tag:iphone] or [tag:ipad] tag also.  I guess the question that needs to be asked is if there are many questions for which that context doesn't matter, i.e. generic [tag:ios-simulator] questions.

Comment: Part of the problem here is how Apple switched from calling it the iPhone SDK to the iOS SDK, renaming the iPhone Simulator to the iOS Simulator (thus all the old iPhone Simulator questions).  There never was an iPad Simulator, it was just a different view within the (poorly named) iPhone Simulator.  Now that this has been renamed to the iOS Simulator, I see no reason to keep the other tags.  This isn't like the [ios] vs. [iphone] tags, where the latter can signify a particular class of device.  Even there, people have migrated over from using [iphone] for everything to [ios] for most stuff.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good idea; there is really not much of a difference between the two, other than size and proportions.

Comment: Actually, there really isn't even a separate application for both.  They're just different layouts in the one iOS Simulator application.

Comment: @BradLarson Exactly.